# How to use a specific list of components in a stream in ASPEN-HYSYS?

Tags: chemical-engineering, software

In HYSYS it is possible to create multiple lists of components using their proper fluid package to better calculate the properties of very different molecules.

Here I defined two lists:

**List 1**
[image: List 1 HYSYS]

**List 2**
[image: List 2 HYSYS]

I also defined the fluid packages I need and when I go to simulation and create a stream, I can only specify the composition for the first list of components as shown after. **How should I do if I want to use the second list of components?**

[image: Stream HYSYS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a whole new property package to use List 1 or 2 even if the EoS is the same as the initial one. There are a few times when this is impossible such as in Sulphur Recovery (Sulsim) or some Acid Gas properties. Also you should know you can share component lists with two property packages because there are times your reactor requires NRTL but your distillation tower requires CPA or it works fine with PR because you have to have the Efficiencies already measured out.

If you want to change component lists within the stream and keep the data from stream 1... You better create 2 streams one with Basis 1 and the other with Basis-2 each one with its own component list.

Edit: Oh also to change the basis you do it in the Fluid Package cell in Worksheet/Conditions (Perhaps this was the answer to your question)